# include_once from codeigniter in EE template

Tags: codeigniter

i'm finishing an EE website that contains a codeigniter intranet part. two setups, two databases. runs smooth.
now i want to include some codeigniter php files into EE.
was thinking to do so via php include, but now it seems that including codeigniter doesn't work for some reason.

i have this:

```
<?php 
include_once './photogallery/index.php'; // works perfect
include_once './CodeigniterIntranet/photogallery/show'; // failed to open stream: No such file or directory
?>
```

any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have a php file named `./CodeigniterIntranet/photogallery/show` (without the `.php` extension)?

Comment: hi scott, no that's the url i use. photogallery is the controller, show the function in the controller

Comment: Well, to `include` that you'll need [URL include wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) enabled in your PHP *and* to specify the include as a URL (if that's really what you want?).

Comment: URL include wrappers solved the issue! thanks :)

Comment: OK, cool -- nice job!